# How do you copy a file to and from an external USB drive in iOS/iPadOS?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, nsfilemanager, react-native-fs

I'm building a react native app where I need to view the contents of an external storage device and copy files to and from said device through my app. On android I'm using an sd card mounted on a USB adapter and connected through a USB C cable). I would like to do something similar in iOS devices, specifically iPads.

On android I'm using the `ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` constant in [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). There doesn't seem to be an alternative for iOS.

I'm happy to write native code if need be and use the JS bridge, although I'am new to swift development. **I just want to know whether it is possible to access external storage drives over USB on iOS devices, and if so where to find information about it.**

I have looked through apple's `FileManager` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) and can't seem to find anything. I'm also finding apple's documentation hard to navigate through and extract useful information out of. I'm wondering if that's a common experience or am I just new to native iOS development and therefore going through some steep learning curve when reading apple's docs.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am attempting something similar and can't find any information anywhere on it.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer either. The interim solution we have adopted is to back up the contents in the iOS document folder and then manually copy it to an external USB device when needed. Not ideal but gets the job done for now.